# get_results on large datasets

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am experimenting some very disturbing problem using a custom SQL query.
I have a custom MySQL table called `trading_datas` having 165 lines for 4,4Mo. One field `datas` of my table is a big serialized array.

When requesting over it that way:

```
$querystr = "SELECT item, datas FROM trading_datas";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $querystr, 'ARRAY_A' );
```

my PHP script stops and nothing gets echoed right after that line.
When retrieving only `item` everything works great.

Should I zip my serialized array before putting it in database? Any other solution?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Side note: I do advise to use a the table `prefix`

Comment: Any reason since its only for personnal purpose?

Comment: If it's a WP site you should follow the WP standards, there is no reason not to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$wpdb` doesn't suit for fetching huge amount of data from database. Why? In your case:

1. `$wpdb->get_results( ... )` - fetches all results into your RAM at once. It means if you have 4mb, 10mb, or 50mb of data in db, everything will be stored in memory (what is limited as you know).
2. `$wpdb->get_results( ..., ARRAY_A )` - `$wpdb` fetches everything as object by default, and then if you pass `ARRAY_A`, it will convert array of objects into array of associated arrays. It means that if you've already fetched `4mb`/`10mb`/`50mb` of data into memory, you have to multiply it 2 or even more times.

So, I suppose your issue is in reaching memory limit by your script. That's why it works for one result and doesn't work for all results. There is one workaround for this issue - use `mysql_*` function in the way you need it:

```
$result = @mysql_query( "SELECT item, datas FROM trading_datas", $wpdb->dbh );
if ( $result ) {
    while ( ( $row = @mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) ) {
        // do stuff here for each result ...
    }
    @mysql_free_result( $result );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll give it a try and valid your answer as soon as I'll have tested it